# Openshift configure for v2 to v3 migration

Tags: openshift

So I've been running my personal website on openshift v2 to v3 for awhile. I'm 99.9% sure that nothing on my website actually requires much migration (custom js that just pulls static files - no databases [yet] and no real dynamic content generation [other than 404 pages]).

I honestly don't remember how I set up the system, but I have it such that if I push to the master branch of a particular git repo it automatically updates the site. Until now its been an out of sight out of mind situation. But now v2 is being deprecated.

Reading through the documentation for migration it looks like my custom js should be fine. However from what I gather I will have to host my code on github instead of the openshift repo I was provided. I can post the github link if necessary.

Now all I needed to do was use the oc command listed on https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/migrating_applications/web_framework_applications.html#dev-guide-migrating-web-framework-applications-node.js

However to do that I need to setup oc. I tried using oc login but I have no idea what to use for the server.

Do I need to use oc to migrate my application? What do I use for the server configuration?

I'm pretty out of my element here, I mostly use low-level languages and mess with linux internals. I'm used to having access to every line of code that gets run, but here I have to figure out how to make my code compatible with openshift.

Comment: Have you signed up for OpenShift Online 3 yet? Either way, visit https://manage.openshift.com/, subscribe to a plan, and then click on the "Open Web Console" link to visit the web console for your cluster. Login to the cluster, click the ? help dropdown in the upper right, and click on command line tools. There should be an `oc login ...` command there for you to copy/paste. If you know the name of your cluster, you can just login with `oc login https://api.<plan>-<cluster-region-id>.openshift.com/`, where plan is 'starter' or 'pro' and cluster region id is something like 'us-east-1'.

Comment: Thank you, that mostly worked. Now I just can't figure out how to get my domain to link to the v3 app instead of the v2 one. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: To get a feel for using OpenShift V3, try out https://learn.openshift.com/ It gives live exercises you can do and also includes one about accessing a cluster.

Comment: So I think I did it correctly, but I don't know how to modify my DNS CNAME (though I remember doing so before - iirc its pretty straightforward from the domain provider's site) or what to set it to? The tutorial says to set the CNAME to "the hostname mapping to the hostname for the OpenShift cluster's router" but I don't know what the hostname of the cluster's router is?

Comment: The easier way is to create a route and leave hostname as empty. OpenShift will then generate a hostname for you. Then set the CNAME to that hostname. Then create a second route (using a different name for it), with your actual custom hostname. Leave both routes in place. That saves working out how to get the inbound router address.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Now my only issue is that when I go to the route that was automatically generated I get an "Application not available" page. I feel like I'm somehow missing a step to 'enable' it.

Comment: If you're on the Starter tier, you will be unable to use your custom domain. Only the Pro tier offers custom domains.

Comment: @WillGordon I already have my own domain though. I should be able to just forward the CNAME shouldn't I? At this point even the automatically generated page forwards me to the Application not available page. I have checked the pod and it is running.

Comment: It sounds like you might be hitting this [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1490491). Does the route start to work after 10-15 minutes? Also, the restriction of custom domains on Starter tier is because Starter is for experimentation and testing. The router will not accept any incoming traffic not over the default route. This restriction is not in place for Pro.

Comment: So openshift no longer provides free node application hosting for custom domains, eh? Do you know of a webservice that would? Or a cheaper way to get openshift to do it. 50$/mo is waaay overkill for a personal website, but ~5$/mo would be viable for me.